# How to use a VAR value from a function in another?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm Bruno and I started learning HTML/CSS/JS this month, I would like to know how can I use a var value from a function in another? I tried to create different functions to bring me the operator and numbers typed and then I'll use the if statement to check if the operator and numbers are typed, but the console.log(operador) is returning undefined.

Could you please share some tips on how can I fix this issue on my code?

Thank you so much :)

```js
function oper(value) {
  var operacao = document.getElementById("operador").value = value;
}

function num(value) {
  var operador = oper(value);
  var current = document.getElementById("numeral").value += value;

  if (current === "" && operator === "") {
      var checkfalse = false
    } 
    else if (current !== "" && operator !== "") {
      var checktrue = true
    }
      console.log(operador)
}


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
section.linha-1 div{
  display: inline-block;

}
section.linha-2 div{
  display: inline-block;
}

section.linha-3 div{
  display: inline-block;

}

section.linha-4 div{
  display: inline-block;

}

section.linha-5 div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculadora</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>Calculadora (HTML/CSS/JavaScript)</header>
    <section class="tela-iphone">
      <section class="tela-display">
          <div class="display">
              <input class ="tela-display" id="tela-display" type="text" readonly>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section class="linha-1">
          <div class="AC">
            <button class="limpar" id="limpar" onclick="ac()" value="limpar"> AC</button>
          </div>
          <div class="positivo-negativo">
              <button class="mais-menos" id="mais-menos" onclick="maismenos()" value="maismenos">+/-</button>
          </div>
          <div class="percentual">
              <button class= "percentual" id="percentual" onclick="percentual()" value="percentual">%</button>
          </div>
          <div class="divisao">
              <button class="divisao" id="operador" onclick="oper('÷')" value="÷">÷ </button>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section class="linha-2">
          <div class="sete">
              <button class="sete" id="numeral" onclick="num(7)" value="7">7</button>
          </div>
          <div class="oito">
              <button class="oito" id="numeral" onclick="num(8)" value="8">8</button>
          </div>
          <div class="nove">
              <button class="nove" id="numeral" onclick="num(9)" value="9">9</button>
          </div>
          <div class="multiplicacao">
              <button class="multiplicacao" id="operador" onclick="oper('×')" value="*">×</button>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section class="linha-3">
          <div class="quatro">
              <button class="quatro" id="numeral" onclick="num(4)" value="4">4</button>
          </div>
          <div class="cinco">
              <button class="cinco" id="numeral" onclick="num(5)">5</button>
          </div>
          <div class="seis">
              <button class="seis" id="numeral" onclick="num(6)" value="5">6</button>
          </div>
          <div class="subtracao">
              <button class="subtracao" id="operador" onclick="oper('-')" value="-">-</button>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section class="linha-4">
          <div class="um">
              <button class="um" id="numeral" onclick="num(1)" value="1">1</button>
          </div>
          <div class="dois">
              <button class="dois" id="numeral" onclick="num(2)" value="2">2</button>
          </div>
          <div class="tres">
              <button class="tres" id="numeral" onclick="num(3)" value="3">3</button>
          </div>
          <div class="adicao">
              <button class="adicao" id="operador" onclick="oper('+')" value="+">+</button>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section class="linha-5">
          <div class="zero">
              <button class="zero" id="numeral" onclick="num(0)" value="0">0</button>
          </div>
          <div class="virgula">
              <button class="virgula" id="virgula" onclick="virgula()" value="virgula">,</button>
          </div>
          <div class="resultado">
              <button class="resultado" id="resultado" onclick="resultado('=')" value="=">=</button>
      </section>
    </section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) at the end of your function `oper`, like this:

```js
function oper(value) {
  var operacao = document.getElementById("operador").value = value;
  console.log(operacao);
  return operacoa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeira coisa e bem simples:

O que está retornando sua função 'oper'?

se não está retornando nada, a variável 'operador' fica vazia.

very simple: 'oper' function needs a return statement

Comment: Oi Martino! Obrigado por responder! Coloquei um console.log na função oper não retorna nada, porém quando coloco o log na variável dentro dessa função retorna certinho, tens alguma ideia do que seja?

Comment: @BrunoViana vc colocou 'return console.log(operador)' ?
ou colocou assim:
/*
console.log('qualquer coisa')
return opecacao
*/
na funcao 'oper' só existe a variavel operacao.
sendo assim, deve retornar operacao ---- return operacao // (na funcao oper)
a partir daí, se chamar multiplicacao, por exemplo:
'operador = operacao' --- que retorna o value que está no html
'operador = *' 

admito que não entendi muito bem seu ultimo comentario, mas tentei explicar conforme o entendimento.

Comment: Primeiro coloquei na variavel fora da função: var operacao;
function oper(value) {
operacao = document.getElementById(“operador”).value = value;
}
console.log(operacao); Onde não me retornou resultado, aí coloquei dentro da função: function oper(value) {
  operacao = document.getElementById("operador").value = value;
  console.log(operacao);
} e retornou certinho

Comment: Sim, agora sei por que.

vamos lá: se vc colocar fora da função, o console.log vai ser chamado antes mesmo da função, pela ordem de precedência.

a sua variavel 'operacao' só recebe algum valor após o funcao 'num' chamar a variável 'operador', que chama/recebe/assign a funcao 'oper' e, a partir daí a varíavel 'operacao' entra em cena.

antes disso, qualquer variável que esteja fora de alguma dessas funções irá retornar vazio/nulo. Espero ter ajudado.

ps: te adicionei no linkedin. precisando de ajuda, só dar um alô.

Comment: MARAVILHOSO! Coloquei minhas funções na ordem respeitando a ordem de precedência! SUPER funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there are a few ways to do this:

## Method #1: Returning

Simply use the `return` keyword to make you function return a value when run:

```js
function oper(value) {
  var operacao = document.getElementById("operador").value = value;
  return operacoa;
}

console.log(oper("value here"));//Outputs the value of the operacoa variable
```

## Method #2: Global variables:

You can also use globally scoped variables, however, returning is a much cleaner solution:

```js
//Declare the variable
var operacao;

function oper(value) {
  operacao = document.getElementById("operador").value = value;
}

oper("value");

console.log(operacao); //Logs the output.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make the variable global you can try this method.

```
function a() {
var x = 10
b(x)
}

function b(arg1) {
console.log(arg1)
/** You can get the value of x even though it is from another function, but try not to use this method for recursive actions as you might hit the function recursion limit **/
}

a()
```